# Kafka streams - exactly once configuration

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I was trying to use exactly once capabilities of kafka using kafka streams library. I've only configured proessing.guarantee as exactly_once. Along with this, there is a need to have transaction state stored in a internal topic (__transaction_state).

My question is, how to customize the name of the topic? if kafka cluster is being shared by multiple consumers, does each customer need a different topic for transaction management?

Thanks
Murthy

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the topic `__transaction_state` -- it's an internal topic that will be automatically created for you -- you don't need to create it manually and it will always have this name (it's not possible to customize the name). It will be used for all producers that use transactions.